# Dynamically hide/show region in interactive report(Oracle APEX 5.1)

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am developing an application which has many region in interactive report.

Now, I want to hide some of the region  in the interactive report. Is it possible to do it in APEX? I am using Oracle APEX 5.1.

I Add server side condition for region of interactive report that we want to hide based on the condition.

I USE THIS  CODE IN SERVER SIDE CONDITION :

```
Declare
   l_status   pls_integer;
begin
  begin
   select ID  into l_status
   from  TABLE_1 where id =:ID;
   exception 
   when others then l_status  := 0 ;
   end ;
   if nvl(l_status ,0) = 0 then
     return true;
   else
     return false;
   end if;
end;
```

WHEN DYNAMIC ACTION IS TRUE THEN I USE HIDE ACTION FOR HIDE REGION BUT Does not work .
can someone help ?

Answer (score 1):

A server side condition is evaluated when the page is rendered. If a component on the page is not rendered because the server side condition yielded false, it is not part of the dom and it cannot be shown using a dynamic action.
If you want to use a dynamic action to show/hide a component, then you have to hide it first (for example with an onload dynamic action).

Comment: No problem, could please mark the question as answered ?